# NLog: Force BufferingTargetWrapper to empty on AppDomain UnhandledException

Tags: c#, nlog, unhandled-exception

I have NLog configured in my application to to use the `BufferingTargetWrapper` for sending emails with the `MailTarget`.

The problem I'm running into is I can not find a way to force NLog to empty the `BufferingTargetWrapper` before the application exits from Unhandled Exceptions.

I tried calling `LogManager.Flush()` and `LogManager.DisableLogging()` from the Current App Domain's UnhandledException Event but it does not seam to work.

What would I need to do to make it send the emails?

Comment: Are you using a PostFilteringWrapper?  I'd really want to see your .nlog or programmatic configuration.

Comment: I think there is either an extra thread running with the buffer, which doesn't get any timeslice or a pending timer which would need (some) time. did you try some Threading.Thread.Speep(x) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can call the BufferingTargetWrapper and force it to write the logs. Its strange that the LogManger.Flush doesn't work.

```
var buffWapper =
            LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("BufferingTargetWrapper") as BufferingTargetWrapper;
        if (buffWapper != null)
            buffWapper.Flush();
```

or

```
var buffWapper =
            LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("BufferingTargetWrapper") as BufferingTargetWrapper;
        if (buffWapper != null)
        {
            buffWapper.BufferSize = 1;
            buffWapper.Flush();
        }
```