# Buffering log messages in NLog and manually flushes them to target

Tags: c#, logging, wrapper, nlog, buffering

I am trying to log via the NLog MailTarget.
It works just fine, but i wanted to wrap the mailtarget with the `BufferedTargetWrapper` to buffer the log messages until a predefined codepoint, where i want to manually flush the buffer and send the previusly buffered log messages by an single mail (like defined in the mail target).

If I define a `FlushTimeout` or the `BufferSize` of the `BufferedTargetWrapper` everything still works just fine as supposed.
But if the FlushTimeout and the BufferSize is not set, i can't get it to work.

Like answered in this question on SO [Force BufferingTargetWrapper to empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413299/nlog-force-bufferingtargetwrapper-to-empty-on-appdomain-unhandledexception) i have no something like that:

```
 LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.Where(t => t != null && t is BufferingTargetWrapper).ToList().
            ForEach(b => ((BufferingTargetWrapper)b).Flush(null));
```

But the documentation and this answer is contradictory to my NLog Version (2.0.0.2000).
There is no flush method without parameters, only the flush method for asynchronous targets.

Is there a way to force the BufferingTargetWrapper to flush all the logged messages to the wrapped target (to send it by mail)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the documentation your approach should not work, but it is fine. Just give the flush method an empty lambda expression:

```
LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets
    .OfType<BufferingTargetWrapper>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(b => b.Flush(e =>
        {
            //do nothing here
        }));
```