# Should NLog flush all queued messages in the AsyncTargetWrapper when Flush() is called?

Tags: c#, silverlight, nlog

I want to shut down my application and write any pending log messages. So I call `LogManager.Flush()` during my shutdown process. However, I don't see all the messages written out. Instead, if I wait for a few seconds (using `Thread.Sleep()`) I see the messages.

After examining [NLog's code on GitHUB](https://github.com/jkowalski/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/Wrappers/AsyncTargetWrapper.cs), I find the `AsyncTargetWrapper.FlushAsync()` method is only scheduling the lazy writer thread to write all pending messages on the next batch. It is not writing log messages synchronously.

Is this the expected behaviour? I'm expecting `LogManager.Flush()` to be synchronous, ie: to block until all pending messages are written (or the timeout is exceeded).

---

Code I use on shutdown:

```
LogManager.Flush(ex => { }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

And then the code to initialise Nlog (this is a Silverlight app, so I'm not using any config files).

```
    public static void InitialiseNLog(LogLevel forLevel)
    {
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // Add targets.
        // We need an async target wrapping a custom web service call back to the server.
        var serverTarget = new RemoteServiceTarget();
        var asyncWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper(serverTarget, 10000, AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Discard);
        asyncWrapper.TimeToSleepBetweenBatches = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).TotalMilliseconds;
        asyncWrapper.BatchSize = 200;

        // Add rules.
        var rule = new LoggingRule("Company.Application.SilverlightApp.*", forLevel, asyncWrapper);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

        // Activate the configuration.
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
        LogManager.GlobalThreshold = forLevel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a fix by editing the current NLog source code.

In AsyncTargetWrapper.cs, change the `FlushAsync()` method from:

```
protected override void FlushAsync(AsyncContinuation asyncContinuation)
{
    this.flushAllContinuation = asyncContinuation;
}
```

To:

```
protected override void FlushAsync(AsyncContinuation asyncContinuation)
{
    this.flushAllContinuation = asyncContinuation;
    this.ProcessPendingEvents(null);        // Added to make this flush synchronous.
}
```

Comment: As result FlushAsync function become sync ;-) This is not a fix.

Comment: This is a bit old now, so I can't remember the entire context. But calling `Thread.Sleep()` on shutdown is hardly a better alternative. There's a `LogManager.Shutdown()` method in current NLog, which might be a better alternative (although I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 6):

The comment by [ligos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508571) is on the right track.
The `AsyncTargetWrapper.CloseTarget()` method was modified as a result of [NLog issue 134](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/134), where a nested `BufferingTargetWrapper` wasn't getting flushed on domain unload.

`LogManager.Shutdown()` does indeed force the `AsyncTargetWrapper` to effectively flush synchronously but it would have to be used after `LogManager.Flush()` because targets such as the `BufferingTargetWrapper` don't actually flush on close. It may be better to set `LogManager.Configuration = null` as this performs a flush and then closes the targets in one hit and the configuration will be reloaded (if using configuration file) next time it needs to be used.

I've tested both and I have gone with the latter as I am wanting my logging back up and running after I've put things right, but given the question is in Silverlight I would recommend:

```
LogManager.Flush();
LogManager.Shutdown();
```

**Edit**

`LogManager` sets the config to null on domain unload or process exit so we shouldn't be seeing this problem unless running an old NLog version. The NLog issue was fixed in Oct 2012. Have tested without explicit shutdown or setting config to null and can confirm that calling `LogManager.Flush()` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Flagrantly stolen from:  [Buffering log messages in NLog and manually flushes them to target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153286/buffering-log-messages-in-nlog-and-manually-flushes-them-to-target)

```
LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets
.OfType<BufferingTargetWrapper>()
.ToList()
.ForEach(b => b.Flush(e =>
    {
        //do nothing here
    }));
```