# NLog FileTarget on SSD slower than HDD in benchmark?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

| Method | storage | loggingFramework | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LogInfo | HDD | Nlog | 317.5 ns | 68.74 ns | 3.77 ns | 1 | 0.0196 | 0.0067 | - | 149 B |
| LogInfo | SSD | Nlog | 321.3 ns | 221.72 ns | 12.15 ns | 2 | 0.0191 | 0.0067 | - | 145 B |
| LogInfo | RamDisk | Nlog | 326.7 ns | 72.90 ns | 4.00 ns | 3 | 0.0200 | 0.0072 | - | 152 B |
| LogInfo | RamDisk | Log4Net | 6,246.7 ns | 330.27 ns | 18.10 ns | 4 | 0.0305 | - | - | 216 B |
| LogInfo | HDD | Log4Net | 7,874.0 ns | 20,773.26 ns | 1,138.65 ns | 5 | 0.0305 | - | - | 216 B |
| LogInfo | SSD | Log4Net | 8,360.2 ns | 26,805.20 ns | 1,469.28 ns | 6 | 0.0305 | - | - | 216 B |

```
[Benchmark]
public void LogInfo()
{
    //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    //{
    Logger.Info(depthMessage);
    //}
}
```

The question is not clear because I am new to log framework. Obviously, log is not written to disk directly, which leads to benchmark failure. I cannot delete question. I share my config here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="false" >
    <variable name='globalLevel' value='info'/>
    <variable name="LogDay" value="${date:format=yyyyMMdd}"/>
    <variable name="LogHour" value="${date:format=yyyyMMdd-HH}"/>
    <variable name="LogHour" value="${date:format=yyyyMMdd-HH}"/>
    <variable name="shortlogtime" value="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss.fff}"/>
    <targets>
        <target name="SSDRollingFileAppender" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\Nlog\${LogDay}.log"
                    layout="${shortlogtime}${message}"
                    maxArchiveFiles="100"
                    archiveAboveSize="5368709120"
                    archiveNumbering="Sequence"
                    concurrentWrites="false"
                    keepFileOpen="true"
                    
                    archiveFileName="c:\Nlog\${LogDay}.{##}.log"
                    />


        <target name="HDDRollingFileAppender" xsi:type="File" fileName="d:\Nlog\${LogDay}.log"
                    layout="${shortlogtime}${message}"
                    maxArchiveFiles="100"
                    archiveAboveSize="5368709120"
                    archiveNumbering="Sequence"
                    concurrentWrites="false"
                    keepFileOpen="true"
                    
                    archiveFileName="d:\Nlog\${LogDay}.{##}.log"
                    />

        <target name="RamDiskRollingFileAppender" xsi:type="File" fileName="e:\Nlog\${LogDay}.log"
                    layout="${shortlogtime}${message}"
                    maxArchiveFiles="100"
                    archiveAboveSize="5368709120"
                    archiveNumbering="Sequence"
                    concurrentWrites="false"
                    keepFileOpen="true"
                    
                    archiveFileName="e:\Nlog\${LogDay}.{##}.log"
                    />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="SSD" minlevel="${globalLevel}" writeTo="SSDRollingFileAppender" final="true" />
        <logger name="HDD" minlevel="${globalLevel}" writeTo="HDDRollingFileAppender" final="true" />
        <logger name="RamDisk" minlevel="${globalLevel}" writeTo="RamDiskRollingFileAppender" final="true" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: You can see there's no big difference between HDD and SSD for Nlog. So why? Thanks

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you making sure that the data gets flushed to disk too?

Comment: you always need to be careful with what you are measuring. It is likely you are measuring the time to write to some buffer. Also, what is the actual problem? SSDs in general have better performance than spinning disks, but if logging is a performance bottleneck you probably need other fixes.

Comment: For Nlog, to have the benchmark make sense you'll probably also want to make sure all loggers are flushed as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248256/51685

Comment: No config, no clear question. This is really unclear

Answer (score 1):

NLog FileTarget is by default running with the [handbreak pulled](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2758). Please configure these settings for the NLog FileTarget and run your benchmark again:

- KeepFileOpen = true
- ConcurrentWrites = false

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance#file-logging-performance

P.S. If you want really fast performance, then you should also enable [AsyncWrapper](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target), but [remember to flush](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush) and also notice that by default overflowAction = Discard.